# Is there a way to connect my computer that cannot connect to wireless wifi to a wifi signal? There is no network cable in my house

Tags: internet

I have a desktop computer. But I can only access the Internet when there is a network cable, but I want to move the desktop computer to the room on the second floor, and I don't want to do a lot of decoration to arrange the network cable. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Put a wireless card or a USB Wireless Adapter in the Desktop computer. Make sure it works and can connect to your wireless router.

Put a wireless router as near to the second floor room as you can.

Now move the computer to the second floor and test it. You may need to adjust the position of the wireless router for best results.

(**Note:** I do roughly this and work in my second floor office all the time).